# What wavelength of light should I use to measure the absorbance of an anabaena population?

Tags: algae, spectroscopy

I am trying to use a spectrophotometer/colorimeter to measure the relative amounts of anabaena (cyanobacteria) in different samples.

What wavelength should I use to get the maximum absorbance?

Comment: Welcome to the Biology Stack. Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] for more information on this site and how it works. Please also note the [homework](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework) page - so what have you found in the literature about measurements of Anabaena cell density using spectrophotometry? I can find the result within the first few papers on PubMed.